# Android force landscape when Login with Facebook/Twitter

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

My app is in landscape all the time. I have put **`android:screenOrientation="landscape"`** in **AndroidManifest**. But the trouble is, when my app is in landscape, I need to Login with Facebook/Twitter, it shows a dialog in portrait to login and authorize (the device doesn't turn on ***rotation***).

*Is it possible to force the 3rd party app in landscape ?*

Comment: is it in dialog ?(the 3rd party app)

Comment: Facebook open a window to enter username  + password to authorize. It looks like a dialog. 
Twitter open in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure . try to add below code on that dialog,

```
    private void preventScreenRotation() {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
             getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else {
 getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank for answering but it doesn't work, even I put it in onWindowFocusChanged of the activity. We can not change code of the 3rd party app.